# Full Width dropdowns under grid parents

Tags: html, css, grid, css-float, css-position

What is the best method to have a full width dropdown under a grid element.  My grid is set up for each item to be 25% width and the items are floated.  When they are clicked, a child item (the description) will unfold underneath the row of its parent and needs to push the other grid items down.  I am having trouble with making this happen.  My grid is set up as follows:

```
<div class="wrapper" id="content">

    <div class="quarter">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="wrap">
                <h5>Experiments</h5>
            </div><!--end icon-wrap-->
        </div><!--end inner-->  
    </div><!--end quarter-->

   <!-- and then 30 more "quarter" instances

 </div>

 width:25%;
 float:left;
 padding:15px;
 box-sizing:border-box;
```

I am easily able to set up a child that is full width inside of each 'quarter' div, but how can I get it to push the rest of the grid down and not break the grid?

Here's a fiddle...https://jsfiddle.net/2j0xscjd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your css code

```
 .quarter:nth-child(4n+1){clear: both;}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work as I only need the 'description' to be shown on click...I could increase the height of the 'quarter' element on click to make room for the full width 'description' but then the other rows would be pushed down as well.

Comment: than the description needs an position: absolute; so it doesn't interfere with the box. and quarter needs position:relative; so you can move the description relative to your box.

Comment: Then how to push the other boxes down when I do open up the active 'description', though?

Comment: ah i think i know now what you are trying to accomplish. You want  the next line moving further down when the description will be shown. Well i think that will not work when the description is located inside the box. But if you structure it like that 4x boxes > 4x description > 4x boxes > 4x description making the description diplay:none and with:100% you can blend them in via js and they will move the other content acordingly

Comment: Yea Rudi, that's what I want but the issue in doing it that way is that on mobile there are only two items per row.

Comment: ok found a solution just ad this and it works XD

.quarter:nth-child(4n+1){clear: both;}

you can adjust the number to 2n+1 for your mobile view

Comment: Thanks, Rudi.  That works great. Thanks for sticking with me on this ;)